# How to get the min value of an object in a list (C++)

Tags: c++, search, stl

I've a question to ask.

So, I have a structure call **Node** as shown below:

```
struct Node
{
    int xKoor, yKoor;

    Node *parent;                                                                   
    char nodeId;                                                                    

    float G;
    float H;
    float F;

    Node(int x, int y, int id, Node * par)
    {
        xKoor = x;
        yKoor = y;
        nodeId = id;
        parent = 0;
    }

    Node(int x, int y, char id)                                                     
    {
        xKoor = x;
        yKoor = y;
        nodeId = id;
    }
};
```

And I have list that contains elements of this structure:

```
list<Node*> OPEN;
```

This list's size varies in time.

What I need to do is to **find the Node object which has the minimum F value**, then pop out that object from the list.

So, I tried to write a function as shown below:

```
void enKucukFliNodeBul(list<Node*> OPEN)
{

    list<Node*>::iterator it = OPEN.begin();

    for(it = OPEN.begin(); it != OPEN.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it._Ptr->_Myval->F < it._Ptr->_Next->_Myval->F)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But I'm stuck. I'm new to STL. How can I solve this?

My best regards...

Comment: `(*it)->F` instead of `it._Ptr->_Myval->F`. And you need 2 iterators. It's like you're iterating through a 1D array - use on iterator for the current position and one - for the next. Or the opposite.

Comment: Don't worry about STL, C++ or anything similar yet. Start by working out the algorithm in pseudocode, or even, heaven forbid, a flowchart...

Comment: Please! Do no use use internal implementation details! Treat anything from the standard library that starts with an underscore as if it **does not exist**. They are not part of the interface. (I'd be surprised if the code even compiles)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Hi sir, I don't actually understand what you mean.

Comment: BTW Why do you want to store linked nodes in an `std::list`? It is a linked list already, so what you are doing seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) with a suitable comparison function for this.

```
bool nodeComp(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs) {
  return lhs->F < rhs->F;
}


#include <algorithm> // for std::min_element

list<Node*>::iterator it = std::min_element(OPEN.begin(), OPEN.end(), nodeComp);
```

This assumes that `list<Node*>` is `std::list<Node*>`, in which case you should be aware that `std::list` itself is a linked list.

Other useful operations, based on your comments:

Remove a minimum value node from the list and delete it:

```
OPEN.erase(it);
delete *it; //
```

You may need to perform other operations, if your nodes depend on each other.

Sort the list:

```
OPEN.sort(nodeComp);
```

Comment: Hi, so if delete 'it', will it be popped out from the list? if so, I just need to say delete *it?

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim You would need to remove it from the list too, using the first version of [std::list::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase). If you just delete it, the list will contain a pointer to some memory location that cannot be used.

Comment: sir one more question, is it possible to sort the list by min value of F? So the starting element will have the least F value.

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim `std::list` has a sort method which takes a comparator:  `OPEN.sort(nodeComp)`.

Comment: Thank you, well appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use `std::min_element` algirithm and overload Compare function

```
bool compareF(Node *lhs, Node *rhs) 
{
 return lhs->F < rhs->F; 
}
```

if you are using C++03:

```
std::<Node*>::itertor ter = std::min_element(OPEN.begin(),OPEN.end(), compareF);
```

if you are using C++11:

```
auto iter = std::min_element(OPEN.begin(),OPEN.end(), compareF);
```

To sort the list, you can call `OPEN.sort(compareF);` to sort your list with `compareF` function

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I delete iter from list and add to another list?

Comment: You don't need to delete iter

Comment: I want to delete it from list after I find the minimum value.

Comment: oh, use std::remove and std::erase algorithm

Comment: @billz `std::list::erase` is enough.

Comment: +1 for the head up. It's recommended to call member functions if container provides.

Comment: @billz sir, is it possible to sort the list by min value of F? So the starting element will have the least F value.

Comment: yes, you can sort your list by calling: `OPEN.sort(compareF);`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
bool compare_node_F(Node* n1, Node* n2)
{
  return n1-> F< n2-> F;
}

#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::list<Node*> nodes;
  for(int i= 100; i--;)
  {
    Node* n= new Node(42, 42, 42);
    n-> F= i;
    nodes.push_back(n);
  }
  std::list<Node*>::iterator min_element_iter= std::min_element(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), compare_node_F);
  std::cout<< "Min F: "<< (*min_element_iter)-> F<< '\n';
  for(std::list<Node*>::iterator d= nodes.begin(); d!= nodes.end(); ++ d)
    delete *d;
}
```